# Shell script command to drop a column from CSV file

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to drop a column (I get this as variable from pre-process) from a csv file.

I looked at examples provided and tried the below

```
cut -d ',' -f 2 X.csv > Y.csv
```

Above command is not helping - 2nd column from X.csv is copied to Y.csv

I want 2nd column to be dropped along with the delimiter

Eg:

```
name,place,animal
a,chicago,python
b,new york,squirrel
```

After using cut command the file should look like

```
name,animal
a,python
b,squirrel
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of choosing the one you want to drop, choose the ones you want to store!

```
cut -d ',' -f 1,3- X.csv > Y.csv
```

Anyways, if you prefer to drop a column instead of keep the others (same thing, different point of view), you can also use the complement flag:

```
cut -d ',' -f 2 --complement X.csv > Y.csv
```

Comment: I have about 150 columns in few files - that will not help !!

Comment: The syntax I gave you will work with as many columns as you have. Anyways, I added the `complement` flag, which is closer to your mind setup.

Comment: what about escaped `,`?

Comment: @madhavg if you use the second syntax, you only specify which columns you wish to drop. so if you are dropping 1 column out of 150 it is still one number.

Answer (score 3):

`man cut`:

```
--complement
       complement the set of selected bytes, characters or fields
```

Let's try it:

```
$ cut -d , -f 2 --complement file
name,animal
a,python
b,squirrel
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use csvcut from csvkit

https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/scripts/csvcut.html

The `-C` offers the functionality you are looking for

```
   -C NOT_COLUMNS, --not-columns NOT_COLUMNS
                        A comma separated list of column indices, names or
                        ranges to be excluded, e.g. "1,id,3-5". Defaults to no
                        columns.
```

Answer (score 0):

many languages ship with CSV parsing modules. I like ruby's for one-liners:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) do |row|
    row.delete_at 1   # "1" is the 2nd field due to 0-based array indexing.
    puts row.to_csv
  end
' file.csv
```

or, if you like one line oneliners

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| row.delete_at 1; puts row.to_csv}' file.csv
```